# "What is the name of that song" kind of questions

Tags: feature-request

In movies.stackexchange.com there is a find that movie tag where the asker of a question describe the story and the other members help him find out the name of the movie (or similar).

Can we have similar on topic questions here? For example, someone posting a link to an audio clip and asking for identification of the song. I know that those questions are off-topic at the moment. But I want to talk about the feasibilities of having such questions "on-topic".

Comment: If they were to be on topic somewhere, it would be on the [Music Fans SE](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/). Even there these questions have been decided to be off topic, much related to peoples dislike of those questions on Movies SE. So I think the chance of this happening is quite slim.

Comment: There are several other discussions besides the one linked as the duplicate.  Please don't start another unless you have a significant new reason that hasn't been addressed.

Comment: @MatthewRead: In all fairness, the discussion you linked to does not give a conclusive answer. Not that I want this one reopened.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to happen here for a few reasons:

1. It doesn't fit our scope at all. [This is from our tour page](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour):

   > Music Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for musicians, students, and enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about music practice, performance, composition, technique, theory, or history.

   This site is more for people who make, study, and preform music rather then consume it. Like MeaningfulUsername said if it would be on-topic anywhere it would be the [Music Fan SE](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/), but not here. It would be like trying to ask movie identification questions on a site devoted to making movies.
2. Even if it was in our scope, these types of questions really would not be good for anyone but the person asking. A question with the title "What is the name of this song?" and just a recording *may* be answerable, but even if someone else has the same question how will they find it? If the title of the song is put into the it wouldn't be much of an identification question and even if you include the source like "What is the name of this song from X show?" or "What is the name of this song from X video?" the searchability of the question does not go up by much.